# Swedish ID validity

Tags: resident-permit, sweden

I lived in Sweden for 2 years until 2008 and have a minor son born there. He resides with me in India on an OCI as I am divorced and my husband moved away from Sweden. Can I bring my son after he is an adult and work and live in Sweden? I have a Swedish ID but need a duplicate ID card and to know if it is valid. I need to change my Indian address on the migration certificate.

Comment: Were you married to a Swedish citizen?

Comment: Is your son a Swedish citizen?

Comment: Yes i was married to a swedish citizen. My son still holds a valid swedish passport. I have my personummer but not the card.